# PyPlot coordinate reader ruined when changing axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Generally when plotting with pyplot we have the current (x,y) values at the bottom right:
[image: Note box]

But, what happens if you relabel? Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.ion()
plt.draw()
plt.plot([(i,i) for i in range(10)])
plt.gca().set_xticklabels((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
plt.draw()
```

You get:

[image: Not good]

As you see the x value is ruined, that is, is no longer displayed. This may make sense for non- numeric labeling, and may be difficult to handle, but this actually happened to me while working with a twin axis, which I need to be a transformation of the first. If I relabel the twin the coordinates do not appear as well, even though the main axis is untouched. **Is there a way to retrieve coordinate display capability?**. If someone feels a code to produce and alter a twin axis is necessary let me know.

Comment: `set_xticklabels` only changes the labels. How do you mean that the x values are ruined? That the point are placed incorrectly according to the labels?

Comment: I posted images exactly showing what happens - the x coordinate does not appear. Apparently there is more to it than just changing the labels.

Comment: They seem to appear? The first time the x range starts from 0, in the second plot starts from 1.

Comment: I'll edit the image, I'm talk about the values on the *bar* below the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `set_xticklabels` is used, it will overwrite the formatter used. So it has to be set again:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.5f'))
```

If you want to display the values transformed somehow, then you have to use `FuncFormatter`, which accepts a function of tick and position, and returns the label. Read about it [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter). To combine it with nice scalar formatting (in the link as well) you can use something like:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(
       lambda t,p,f=yourfunc: ScalarFormatter().format_data_short(f(t))))
```

You probably want to initialize the `ScalarFormatter` outside.

Comment: Could you mention FuncFormatter in your answer for future lookers? Unfortunately this half solves my issue. Apparently when you create a twin axis the coordinates printed at the bottom are associated with that axis. I tried to use `plt.axes(originalaxes)` but that didn't help. Do you have any idea how to fix that? If long I'll post another question. Otherwise I'll edit this one. In any case I'll accept your answer once you show FuncFormatter.

Comment: Found a fix - I just delete the original axes from the figure then add them back. Kind of stupid. Anyway please accept my edit.